# Using linq to query the most popular categories C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-core, group-by

I am trying to sift through all orders to find the most popular categories using linq query in .net core3.0.

To make it harder though the category table is 2 joins deep. Below is a depiction of my table schema.

```
Order              ->     Topic          ->     Category
-------------            ------------           ------------
Id                       Id                     Id
TopicId                  CategoryId             Name
```

Is there a way to get a count of which categories were the most popular by querying the orders table? Below is some sample data:

```
Order                   Topic                Category
-------------           ---------------      --------------
Id  TopicId             Id   CategoryId      Id   Name
1   10                  1    2               1    Food
2   10                  2    2               2    Tech
3   3                   3    3               3    Health 
4   5                   5    4               4    Automotive
7   10                  ...                  5    Geography
8   10                  8    8               6    Sports
9   8                   9    8               7    Teaching
                        10   8               8    Programming
```

So based on this I would like to see a result similar to the following:

```
[
 {
   CategoryId: 8, //Programming
   Count: 5
 },
 {
   CategoryId: 3, //Health
   Count: 1
 },
 {
   CategoryId: 4, // Automotive
   Count: 1 
 }
]
```

Below are my c# models

```
[Table("Order")]
public class Order
    {
        [Key, Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(Topic))]
        public int TopicId { get; set; }


        #region Foreign key mappings

        public virtual Topic Topic { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }


[Table("Topic")]
public class Topic
    {
        [Key, Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required, ForeignKey(nameof(Category))]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        #region Foreign key mappings

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }


[Table("Category")]
    public class Category
    {
        public Category()
        {
            this.Topics = new HashSet<Topic>();
        }

        [Key, Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(74)]
        public string Name { get; set; }


        #region Foreign key mappings

        public virtual ICollection<Topic> Topics { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Comment: You have to at least load the Topic relation of the orders to get the Category ID.
Then you can do the stats for the cathegories.
If you want to also show names and other attributes of categories you have to load them as well. 
But it'll be enough to load each category entity just once, not as "deep" joins of Order-and-Topic.

Comment: @jarlh the question has been updated

Comment: Please provide us your class mapping entities so we can take a look how things are mapped in Entity Framework

Comment: @Andre.Santarosa I have added the entity framework models into the question

Comment: You can try to get CategoryIds from  `Category` table and then use `foreach` to count each CategoryId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this output you can use this query.

When you create your joins, LINQ automatically matches the entries and makes easier to get the final result

```
var popularCategories =  (from a in categories
                             join b in topics on a.Id equals b.CategoryId
                             join c in orders on b.Id equals c.TopicId
                          select a).GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                                   .Select(x => new
                                    {
                                       CategoryId = x.FirstOrDefault().Id,
                                       Count = x.Count()
                                    }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).ToList();
```

Comment: With the addition of ".ToList()" before the GroupBy() this solved my problem.

Thank you sir.